# Run eslint "ONLY" on the staged files

Tags: eslint, pre-commit-hook, eslint-config-airbnb, husky, lint-staged

I am trying to use a pre-commit hook to detect eslint errors before commit happens. I am using husky and lint-staged. But it runs the lint command for all the files in src and not on staged files only. Here is my package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "test:ci": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --bail --passWithNoTests",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "precommit": "npm run lint && npm run test:ci"
  }
```

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
```

```
"lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "npm run precommit"
    ],
    "*.jsx": [
      "npm run precommit"
    ]
  }
```

Is there any way so that it works ONLY on staged files and not on other files present in the directory?

Answer (score 6):

With husky v7/lint-staged v11.2.0 - the staged files will simply by added onto the end of your command, separated by spaces. If you have a `.husky/pre-commit` file which calls `npx lint-staged`, and then you have a lint-staged config like so:

```json
{
  '*.js': [
    'eslint'
  ]
}
```

And you modify src/foo.js and src/bar.js, the command that will be run is:

```
eslint src/foo.js src/bar.js
```

Doesn't matter what command you have inside of your lint-staged config. Files are just added onto end of command, separated by spaces.

These files will be passed to your `test:ci` command but they won't make it to your lint subcommand.

You can wrap in bash function... Something like this:

```json
"precommit": "!runIt() { npm run lint $@ && npm run test:ci $@;}; runIt",
```

Wrote this on my phone, and I barely know bash, so syntax might be wrong

Comment: Another question I have, is how to get a list of all .js/ts/tsx/jsx files that have been modified between two git commits, but that will be in a different thread.

Comment: Okay @Devin, but what's the solution??

Comment: Added bash wrapper example

Comment: @DevinRhode regarding "_Files are just added onto end of command, separated by spaces_" do you have a source for that? Couldn't find this in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: I have discovered that myself. It definitely SHOULD be added to the docs!! If you know of a good place to add it, please submit a PR on github ;)

Answer (score 4):

According to this [lint-staged example](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#example-run-eslint-on-entire-repo-if-more-than-10-staged-files), I implemented that in order to lint only staged files (takes like 5 secs) except when there are more than 5 staged files, it checks all the repo (can take more than 1 min):

1. Upgrade `lint-staged` package to the latest version
2. Add a `.lintstagedrc.js` file at the root of your repo. It could contain something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  '**/*.js?(x)': (filenames) =>
    filenames.length > 5 ? 'eslint --ext .js,.jsx . --ignore-path .gitignore --fix .' : `eslint ${filenames.join(' ')} --fix`,
  "*.json": [
    "prettier --write"
  ]
}
```

3. Remove your old "lint-staged" command from the `package.json` file

Answer (score 2):

With the ESLint CLI you have a help parameter `npx eslint -h, --help` or you can check the CLI docs at [the official ESLint docs page/CLI](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface). There's a section related to caching, so that ESLint only looks at files that have been changed.

```
Caching:
  --cache                         Only check changed files - default: false
  --cache-file path::String       Path to the cache file. Deprecated: use --cache-location - default: .eslintcache
  --cache-location path::String   Path to the cache file or directory
  --cache-strategy String         Strategy to use for detecting changed files in the cache - either: metadata or content - default: metadata
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install two libraries, [`husky`](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=automatic-recommended) and [`lint-staged`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged) and you need to configure your `pre-commit` file that you can find inside the `.husky` folder and add this command to it

```
npx lint-staged
```

at the end the file will look like this in case you only want to run eslint

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

Answer (score -5):

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    },
},
"lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
        "eslint src/**/*.{js}",
        "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --bail --passWithNoTests",
        "git add"
    ]
},
```

Comment: If this works, it needs some explanation as to _how_ `eslint src/**/*.{js}` will ONLY lint _staged_ files. I can't see any way that it would work.